# Unexpected result of DataFrame sort

Tags: sorting, dataframe, pandas

When I sort my DataFrame using several columns (`['Symbol','Year','Month','Day']`) the resulting DataFrame is sorted by `Symbol > Year > Month` but **not** by `Day`:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Symbol': {79: 'F', 81: 'F', 82: 'F', 83: 'F', 84: 'F', 85: 'F', 86: 'F', 87: 'F', 89: 'F'}, 'Shares': {79: 100, 81: 100, 82: 100, 83: 100, 84: 100, 85: 100, 86: 100, 87: 100, 89: 100}, 'Month': {79: '08', 81: '08', 82: '08', 83: '08', 84: '08', 85: '08', 86: '08', 87: '08', 89: '09'}, 'Year': {79: '2008', 81: '2008', 82: '2008', 83: '2008', 84: '2008', 85: '2008', 86: '2008', 87: '2008', 89: '2008'}, 'Action': {79: 'Sell', 81: 'Sell', 82: 'Buy', 83: 'Sell', 84: 'Buy', 85: 'Sell', 86: 'Buy', 87: 'Sell', 89: 'Sell'}, 'Day': {79: 2L, 81: 4L, 82: '06', 83: 11L, 84: '13', 85: 18L, 86: '18', 87: 23L, 89: 22L}})

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   Action Day Month  Shares Symbol  Year
79   Sell   2    08     100      F  2008
81   Sell   4    08     100      F  2008
82    Buy  06    08     100      F  2008
83   Sell  11    08     100      F  2008
84    Buy  13    08     100      F  2008
85   Sell  18    08     100      F  2008
86    Buy  18    08     100      F  2008
87   Sell  23    08     100      F  2008
89   Sell  22    09     100      F  2008

In [3]: df.sort(['Symbol','Year','Month','Day'])
Out[3]:
   Action Day Month  Shares Symbol  Year
79   Sell   2    08     100      F  2008
81   Sell   4    08     100      F  2008
83   Sell  11    08     100      F  2008
85   Sell  18    08     100      F  2008
87   Sell  23    08     100      F  2008
82    Buy  06    08     100      F  2008
84    Buy  13    08     100      F  2008
86    Buy  18    08     100      F  2008
89   Sell  22    09     100      F  2008
```

Why isn't [`sort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html) working as expected?

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the smallest reproducing case you've got (as well as mention which version of pandas you're using)?

Comment: Edited accordingly.  Thanks.

Comment: looks like you are using different names to sort than those found in your column headings

Comment: @zach which would throw a KeyError... :s

Comment: What's with those leading zeros (06/08)?  Something seems weird about your data types.  What does `print df_orders.dtypes` give?  Could you edit your post to include `df_orders.to_dict()`?

Comment: zach - those are abbreviated for readability in the forum.

DSM - working on the df_orders.to_dict().  Types are as follows:  Year-object; Month-object; Day-object; Symbol-object; Action-object; Shares-int64

Comment: Edited with to_dict() output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working as you expect because the Days are stored as mixed type (strings and long), and since **strings are "greater than" numbers in python** (the sorting looks like it's acting unexpectedly).

You can convert this column to integers by [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)-ing [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

```
df['Day'] = df['Day'].apply(int)
```

I'd consider doing this for month and year too, since in your DataFrame these are strings (and perhaps would make more sense as int):

```
df['Mo.'] = df['Mo.'].apply(int)
df['Year'] = df['Year'].apply(int)
```

Then you can [`sort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html) by day:

```
In [11]: df.sort(['Day'])
Out[11]:
   Indx  Year  Mo.  Day Sym Action  Shares
0    79  2008    8    2   F   Sell     100
1    81  2008    8    4   F   Sell     100
5    82  2008    8    6   F    Buy     100
2    83  2008    8   11   F   Sell     100
6    84  2008    8   13   F    Buy     100
3    85  2008    8   18   F   Sell     100
7    86  2008    8   18   F    Buy     100
8    89  2008    9   22   F   Sell     100
4    87  2008    8   23   F   Sell     100
```

Or sort with multiple columns:

```
In [12]: df.sort(['Mo.', 'Day'])
Out[12]:
   Indx  Year  Mo.  Day Sym Action  Shares
0    79  2008    8    2   F   Sell     100
1    81  2008    8    4   F   Sell     100
5    82  2008    8    6   F    Buy     100
2    83  2008    8   11   F   Sell     100
6    84  2008    8   13   F    Buy     100
3    85  2008    8   18   F   Sell     100
7    86  2008    8   18   F    Buy     100
4    87  2008    8   23   F   Sell     100
8    89  2008    9   22   F   Sell     100

In [13]: df.sort(['Day', 'Mo.'])
Out[13]:
   Indx  Year  Mo.  Day Sym Action  Shares
0    79  2008    8    2   F   Sell     100
1    81  2008    8    4   F   Sell     100
5    82  2008    8    6   F    Buy     100
2    83  2008    8   11   F   Sell     100
6    84  2008    8   13   F    Buy     100
3    85  2008    8   18   F   Sell     100
7    86  2008    8   18   F    Buy     100
8    89  2008    9   22   F   Sell     100
4    87  2008    8   23   F   Sell     100
```

And with the `ascending` argument:

```
In [14]: df.sort(['Mo.', 'Day'], ascending=[True, False])
Out[14]:
   Indx  Year  Mo.  Day Sym Action  Shares
4    87  2008    8   23   F   Sell     100
3    85  2008    8   18   F   Sell     100
7    86  2008    8   18   F    Buy     100
6    84  2008    8   13   F    Buy     100
2    83  2008    8   11   F   Sell     100
5    82  2008    8    6   F    Buy     100
1    81  2008    8    4   F   Sell     100
0    79  2008    8    2   F   Sell     100
8    89  2008    9   22   F   Sell     100
```

... will work as expected.

Comment: When I attempt that code, I end up with the same output as you, except "Sell"s are first.

Comment: @ErikGibbons interesting... as DSM suggests I think there is something fishy with how you've read in your data (did you use read_csv)? output of df.dtypes and/or df.to_dict() may help :)

Comment: @AndyHayden: now that we've seen `.to_dict()`, you want to take it?

Comment: Does it have something to do with the fact that the "Day"s are splitting between [x]L and just 'x'?  What does that signify?

Comment: @ErikGibbons: yep.  Some of your Days are integers (the "L" stands for "long"), and some are strings.  This is breaking the comparisons, because strings are "greater than" integers, e.g. `100 < '2'` gives True.  Your column should be entirely numeric (integers, floats, doesn't matter here), not in this mixed state.

Comment: That helps a ton.  I'm ENTIRELY at a loss for how they became mixed, but so it goes.  I have direction now, and think I should be able to resolve it from here.  I'll post later if otherwise.  Thanks, you guys were extremely helpful!

Comment: @ErikGibbons You can fix your DatFrame using `df['Day'] = df['Day'].apply(int)` and similarly with `'Mo.'` and `'Year'` :)